# unable to open usb drive in one computer

Tags: usb, windows-8.1, usb-flash-drive

I have a SanDisk 8GB CruzerBlade pen drive which when inserted into my Windows 8.1 system, makes that typical recognizable sound (when inserting and also while removing it) and also shows up for 'Eject Cruzer Blade'.
The Removable Disk (H:) appears in explorer but after quite some time. Upon clicking it, the green color for loading (that is in the background in the address bar, where "This PC" appears) takes a lot of time to reach 100% but the removable disk still cannot be opened.

The files can be accessed when the USB stick is inserted into a different computer and moreover, I can open files of a different pendrive on the first computer using the same port.

I checked the device manager and the driver software is updated according to it.
I am unable to figure out a solution to open the removable disk.

Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Comment: The drive might be dying, as occasionally happens with pen drives. Don't depend on it continuing to work in any way.

Comment: @harrymc I should have mentioned it - it is brand new,

Comment: That doesn't mean much with pen drives.

Comment: @harrymc  Thanks. I tried in three different computers, it works fine but not in this one...still you think it could be the dying pendrive?

Comment: Try it on another USB port in this computer. Sometimes the USB is slightly off on some hardware parameters, and the port is also off but in the opposite direction, so both cannot work together.

Comment: @harrymc Thanks. Had already tried this :-) tried it once more after you advised. In fact also uninstalled the usb drive and scanned for hardware changes in device manager. Removable disk (H:) appears in explorer but that's pretty much about it. On clicking it it goes into loading mode with no success. Any way via command prompt?

Comment: Try the magic solution of booting twice. Apart from this I'm out of ideas, sometimes hardware can be really problematic.

Comment: You've isolated the fault to *this* drive on *this* computer.  When you replace either, the fault vanishes.  So these two are incompatible.  But figuring out why may be more expensive than buying a different drive for $6.

Comment: @harrymc : Thanks very much indeed. Appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: @CamilleGoudeseune: Your point is valid